# Undefined offset on convert csv php

Tags: php, csv

i have a small issue converting a csv file,

The file is converting, but is getting a Notice

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in
Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in

Also i need to group by $row[2] is this possible?

```
<?php

$tsvFile = new SplFileObject('file.csv');
$tsvFile->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);
$tsvFile->setCsvControl("\t");

$file = fopen('file2.csv', 'w');
$header = array('col1', 'col2');
fputcsv($file, $header, ',', '"');

foreach ($tsvFile as $line => $row) {
    if($line > 0) {
        fputcsv($file, array($row[2], $row[4]), ',', '"');
    }
}
fclose($file);

?>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) is usually what you need when referencing an array offset that might not be set.  The explode on the tabs might be getting munged on some rows or something... missing tabs or what not.

Comment: can you please explain more?, thanks

Answer (score 1):

What if some rows have 4 values (columns) when delimited but others only have 1?  Your code assumes a fixed number of $row[] elements.  If you do `isset($row[2])` and it returns false then you know you should not try and access it, which is what causes the notice.

As for why there is no value assigned to that offset I can't say without seeing the CSV.  I've found commas work better than tabs as a delimiter - maybe you have too :)

Not fully sure I know what you mean by 'group by'.  You could easily add a running total inside the foreach, or keep a count in another array using one of the columns as a dimension, with the total per dimension.

Comment: I understand, but doing that is not changing the notice. Thanks allot

Comment: Maybe try [`fgetcsv`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) instead.  Or debug the `foreach ($tsvFile as $line => $row)`.  Use `var_dump` are `$line` and `$row` what you expect?  I am guessing not.

Comment: I see now why is returning offset, is because at the end of the file is a blank line.

Comment: That would do it... `if($line > 0) {` is probably not what you want.  I think what I said about using `isset` is still applicable.  Basically you should not make an assumption that an offset exists unless you explicitly set it.  Anyway, glad you got it sorted.

Comment: Group by i mean, i have 2 columns, code and qty, and the code is repeating, and i need to keep only a unic code.

Comment: Create an array called `$totals`, in the loop do something like '$totals[$row[1]] =+ $row[2];'.  Array will hold total per code at the end.

Comment: do you mean some like this?  $value1 = array($row[2] =+ $row[4]);
  $value2 = $row[4];
  fputcsv($file, array($value1, $value2, ',', '"'));